# VB.Net save excel file only in program debugging

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel

I got a problem which is not an error in writing data to Excel file from VB.NET.
The code to save data in Excel file is as the following:

```
Sub WriteToExcel(ByVal dt As DataTable)
    Dim excel_app As New Excel.ApplicationClass()
    excel_app.Visible = True

    Dim workbook As Excel.Workbook = excel_app.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)
    Dim sheet_name As String = "rptSyncADandITSM"

    Dim sheet As Excel.Worksheet = FindSheet(workbook, sheet_name)

    sheet.Cells(1, "AF") = "Status"
    sheet.Cells(1, "AG") = "Message"
    sheet.Range("AF" & 1).Style.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlign.Top
    sheet.Range("AF1").Style.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlign.Center
    sheet.Range("AF1").ColumnWidth = 10
    sheet.Range("AG1").Style.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlign.Top
    sheet.Range("AG1").Style.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlign.Center
    sheet.Range("AG1").ColumnWidth = 15

    Dim header_range As Excel.Range = sheet.Range("AF1", "AG1")
    header_range.Font.Bold = True
    header_range.Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(Drawing.Color.Black)

    Dim borders As Excel.Borders = header_range.Borders
    borders.LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous
    borders.Weight = 1.9R

    For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
        Dim value_range As Excel.Range = sheet.Range("AF" & dr(0).ToString, "AG" & dr(0).ToString)

        If Not dr.IsNull(0) Then

            sheet.Range("AF" & dr(0).ToString).Style.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlign.Top
            sheet.Range("AF" & dr(0).ToString).Style.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlign.Center
            sheet.Range("AF" & dr(0).ToString).ColumnWidth = 10
            sheet.Range("AG" & dr(0).ToString).Style.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlign.Top
            sheet.Range("AG" & dr(0).ToString).Style.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlign.Center
            sheet.Range("AG" & dr(0).ToString).ColumnWidth = 15

            Dim values(0, 1) As String
            values(0, 0) = dr(1).ToString
            values(0, 1) = dr(2).ToString
            value_range.Value2 = values
        End If

        Dim value_borders As Excel.Borders = value_range.Borders
        value_borders.LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous
        value_borders.Weight = 2.0R
    Next

    workbook.Save()
    workbook.Close()
    'workbook.Close(SaveChanges:=True)
    excel_app.Quit()
End Sub
```

I reference these codes from [this](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_write_excel.html)

But it only works when i debug the program. In runtime(not debugging) doesn't work to save.

Comment: In runtime whatr error u r getting pls explain or post the error

Comment: there is no error @AngularDev. Program execute all codes, but no written data in Excel. But when program is debugged, it works.

Comment: May i get a look of the whole code. because what you are saying should not happen either it should throw exception or it should work correctly.

Comment: now it's ok, but don't know why, same code and i did nothing... anyway thank you @AngularDev